# I can't increment and decrement the index of my table when I click my button

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hello all here is the context I want that when I click on increase that I can decrement the index of my user to make it pass to the next rank, however the problem that I meet and that when I click that one decrements only once here is the code that I made. Other info I'm on a user's page

```
  const handleIncrease = (profil) => {
    const indexRank = ranks.findIndex((t) => t.label === profil.rank);
    const nextRankIndex = Math.max(indexRank - 1, 0);
  };

 <ButtonTransaction
 icon={trending}
 alt={"Bouton pour promouvoir l'employé"}
 title={"Promouvoir"}
 onClick={() => handleIncrease(profil)}
 inactive={profil.indexRank === 0}
 />
```

[image]

I've already tried the same feature for all my users' pages and it works fine, but I don't understand why it doesn't work on a single user

```
  const handleIncrease = (profil) => {
    const newEmployeesList = employees.map((employee) => {
      if (employee.id === profil.id) {
        const indexRank = ranks.findIndex((rank) => rank.label === profil.rank);
        const nextRankIndex = Math.max(indexRank - 1, 0);
        return {
          ...employee,
          rank: ranks[nextRankIndex].label,
          color: ranks[nextRankIndex].color,
          indexRank: nextRankIndex,
        };
      }
      return employee;
    });

    setEmployees(newEmployeesList);
    localStorage.setItem("employees", JSON.stringify(newEmployeesList));
  };
```

[image]